# Referencing other ASP.NET pages symbolically, with compile-time checks?

Tags: asp.net

I'm noticing code accumulating in my project that looks like this:

```
Response.Redirect("/Foo/Bar.aspx");
```

This seems brittle -- if I move or rename Bar.aspx file, I need to find places where I've referenced it and correct those string constants, both in markup and codebehind.  It seems like their should be a better way.  Something like:

```
Response.Redirect( MyNamespace.BarPage.GetUrl() );
```

In other words, let the 'stack' figure out the URL I need.  Note: I know that I can consolidate references to a particular page with a hand-coded BarPage.GetUrl() method, but even that seems failure-prone.

Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you'll face is that there's no real inherent link between a code-behind and it's code-infront except the `<%@Page %>` directive. There's no real reason a codebehind has to even have the same class name as the code-infront's file name, it only happens because it's convention and it's how the auto-generator lays it out.

This means you're not going to find anything you can reference at compile-time that even knows what aspx the .cs links to. The closest thing you'll find is the `typeof(MyNamespace.BarPage).FullName` which will give you the code-behind's name and by assuming things follow convention you could (but I don't recommend) construct the URL for the code infront page it's associated with.

Personally I think you're better off just doing a find-all for `"barPage.aspx"` when you rename it and doing a little refactoring. You'll have to deal with hyperlinks in the code-infront anyway. If `barPage.aspx` represents some abstract concept (Like "The login page") it may help to add a property for it, but if barpage is just another page with no real globally inherent meaning I'd leave it as-is.

Comment: Thanks.  While I'm surprised that ASP.NET does require such significant violation of DRY (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), your answer is the closest thing to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to resource them.   Add a meaningful key and the URL value to the resource file, and redirect that way.

```
Response.Redirect(Properties.ASPXUrls.FooBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a static class with different properties for each of the links. That way, you only have one place to update.

Answer (score 0):

Redirects in general are fragile, no matter how you get the name of the next page. They are also a performance problem.

If you find them collecting in your system, the first question you should really ask is why: excessive redirects are almost always a sign of an architectural problem.

Comment: @ Rick:  I'm not sure why this is necessarily indicative of an architectural problem.  Assuming that I'm responding to a user event (server side) that needs to send the user to a new page ("checkout now", for example), is there an architecturally better way to send the user there?

Comment: There are several ways to avoid redirects. For example, have your page go directly to the new page instead of posting back, using cross-page postbacks or using Server.Transfer().